# HtmlTextBoxFor Loop in MVC 2 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, loops, textbox

I am trying to do something that I think is relatively simple but can't get it to work and would be greatful for some pointers.

I've got a form with a list of text boxes in it... Lets say, I want to find out "Your Favourite Pirates", and get you to list all ten on the page with comments as to why they are your favourite.

So in my view I have:

```
for (int i =1; i <11; i++)         
{%>
    <%=Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Pirate + i, new { size = 30, maxlength = 200 })%>
    <%=Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.PirateReason + i, new { cols = 42, rows = 2 })%>
    <%
}%>
```

But how do I set this up in my model?

Sorry if it wasn't specific.

In my model I just want to store the list of pirates, in the example that I am currently working on there are only 10 pirates so I COULD do it like this if I had to

```
public string Pirate1 { get; set; }
public string Pirate2 { get; set; }
public string Pirate3 { get; set; }
public string Pirate4 { get; set; }
public string Pirate5 { get; set; }
public string Pirate6 { get; set; }
public string Pirate7 { get; set; }
public string Pirate8 { get; set; }
public string Pirate9 { get; set; }
public string Pirate10 { get; set; }
```

But that's horrible, what if I wanted to know your fav 100 Pirates?

I want to store the pirates in the model so I can either pop them in a database or send as an email...

Many thanks for your advice..

Comment: Be more specific. What do you want to set up in your model? Update the list of favourite pirates?

Comment: Sorry I've extended the original question..

Answer (score 1):

Model:

```
public class Pirate
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PirateReason { get; set; }
}
```

Controller action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = Enumerable
        .Range(1, 11)
        .Select(i => new Pirate { 
            Id = i, 
            PirateReason = string.Format("reason {0}", i) 
        });
    return View(model);
}
```

Strongly typed view to `IEnumerable<Pirate>`:

```
<%= Html.EditorForModel() %>
```

Editor Template (`~Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Pirate.ascx`):

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<SomeNs.Pirate>" %>
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Id, new { size = 30, maxlength = 200 }) %>
<%= Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.PirateReason, new { cols = 42, rows = 2 }) %>
```

Comment: That looks like it might do the trick... I'm not at work now to test it out but will be back ;-)